# Is there a word or two that can replace 'greater than or equal to'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

... alternately, **'less than or equal to'**?

If nothing exists, can you suggest something new to be widely adopted?

Comment: "Not less than", at least"; "not greater than", "at most". :)

Comment: If there were a convenient (yet unambiguous) term, mathematics would use it, I'm sure.  But we still struggle along with "greater than or equal to".

Comment: "includes" for sets is abstractly the same relation as "greater than or equal to" for numbers.

Comment: Two or more. Two or less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term [*at least*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-least) is close in meaning to *greater than or equal to*. Example of usage:

- The number of oranges in that bag is *greater than or equal to* twelve.
- There are *at least* twelve oranges in that bag.

Similarly, the term [*at most*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-most) is close in meaning to *less than or equal to*. Example of usage:

- The number of oranges in that bag is *less than or equal to* twelve.
- There are *at most* twelve oranges in that bag.

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't go very well with mathematical and logical context. Compare "_The square root of 2 is greater than or equal to 2_" to "_The square root of 2 is at least 2_". The second one sounds like an opinion-based estimation. Not duly formal.

Comment: @Farid The OP did not restrict answers to a context of formal logic. Let's not presume one.

Comment: That's fair, but I'd personally love to find a word that works well in that context, because that word _would_ work for me!

Comment: @Færd The positive square root of 2 is more than 1 but less than 2, however the positive square root of a half is more than a half but less than 1. I don't find any problem with the terminology in mathematics but I'd be more likely to express it in symbols (<,<=, >=,>) which, when one reads  them, become 'less than', 'less than or equal to', 'greater than or equal to' and 'greater than'. However I'm sure that no one would object to 'at most' and 'at least' as interpretations of the symbols as these are exact descriptions of their meanings.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with these phrases is to find the phrase that means the opposite and then invert it.

If something is greater than or equal to something then the opposite must be *less than*.  So inverted would be *not less than*.

If it's less than or equal to then the inverted opposite would be *not more than* or sometimes *no more than*.

Alternatively you can take the *equal to* value and imply an acceptable variance direction.  For instance *at least X* would be *equal to or greater than X* and *at most Y* would be *equal to or less than Y*.

Phrases like *up to Z* can be somewhat ambiguous and could include or exclude *Z*.